# How to achive the below scenario in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table like below

```
    BILL            BILL_DATE                   TYPE    AMOUNT
    BILL01300002    2016-01-30 15:34:48.957     1       250.00
    BILL01300003    2016-01-30 15:38:00.000     5       150.00
    BILL01300004    2016-01-30 15:49:48.000     5       200.00
    BILL01300002    2016-01-30 16:37:00.433     2       250.00
    BILL01300004    2016-01-30 17:37:00.233     7       1000.00
    BILL01300002    2016-01-30 18:42:54.927     3       250.00
    BILL02020006    2016-02-02 18:42:54.927     3       550.00
```

And I need to show one extra column [AMOUNT2]  based on one case. The case is if the same BILL comes in a same day for three particular TYPE in (1,2,3). Then i need to show the extra column with same amount as TYPE 3 Amount column for those 3 records. other wise the extra column will be 0.

In the #TAB we can find this case in BILL01300002. It has came in a same day.
For 3 particular different TYPES 1,2,3.

My expected Result is

```
    BILL            BILL_DATE                   TYPE    AMOUNT      AMOUNT2
    BILL01300002    2016-01-30 15:34:48.957     1       250.00      250.00
    BILL01300003    2016-01-30 15:38:00.000     5       150.00      0
    BILL01300004    2016-01-30 15:49:48.000     5       200.00      0
    BILL01300002    2016-01-30 16:37:00.433     2       250.00      250.00
    BILL01300004    2016-01-30 17:37:00.233     7       1000.00     0
    BILL01300002    2016-01-30 18:42:54.927     3       250.00      250.00      
    BILL02020006    2016-02-02 18:42:54.927     3       550.00      0
```

I am posting schema for reference

```
        CREATE TABLE #TAB(BILL VARCHAR(250),BILL_DATE DATETIME, TYPE BIGINT, AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2)  )

        INSERT INTO #TAB
        SELECT 'BILL01300002','2016-01-30 15:34:48.957',1, 250
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'BILL01300003','2016-01-30 15:38:00.000',5, 150
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'BILL01300004','2016-01-30 15:49:48.000',5, 200
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'BILL01300002','2016-01-30 16:37:00.433',2, 250
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'BILL01300004','2016-01-30 17:37:00.233',7, 1000
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'BILL01300002','2016-01-30 18:42:54.927',3, 250
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'BILL02020006','2016-02-02 18:42:54.927',3, 550
```

Comment: Do you need that Extra Column AMOUNT2 in Select Query or As in Table as Computed Column ?

Comment: I dont know whether it can be done by computed column or not. But I need it in select query..

Comment: There are two differenct amount for Type 3 (550.00 and 250.00) which one need to peek if above condition get fulfilled ?

Comment: The amount which is having TYPE 3. For BILL01300002 having only one  Type 3 record. I have edited question with schema.

Comment: I need this extra column if the Same bill, same day comes with TYPe1&2&3

Comment: yeah same day. i.e we need to consider only date not time. @tinka

Comment: The Same Bill came in a same day(No time considered) and came with TYPE 1,2& 3 is the only 1 bill that is BILL01300002  @tinka

Comment: Can you explain how come the value 550 comes in your expected result in Amount-2 column

Comment: BILL01300002  having 3 records with TYPE1, 2,3. This is the TYPE 3 records AMOUNT value i.e550

Comment: Sry for wrong data. Now I have edited expected Result @tinka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT *,
       ( CASE B.BILL
           WHEN (SELECT A.BILL
                 FROM   #TAB AS A
                 WHERE  TYPE IN( 1, 2, 3 )
                 GROUP  BY A.BILL
                 HAVING Count(A.BILL) >= 3) THEN amount
           ELSE 0
         END ) AS amount2
FROM   #TAB AS B
```

:) Hoping to help you

Comment: Thank you but it will fetch only the amount column. we can't say its the amount of TYPE 3. I will rest of the code. Thanks anyway

Comment: sorry,my English is not good.so It is not very clear what you mean.i want learn English and help forign friend how to code.

Comment: Nobody is perfect. Neither me nor you. But your code gave me an idea. Thank you

Comment: nice,i'm very glad to hlep you

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
    SELECT *,
       CASE
         WHEN ( Count(bill)
                  OVER (
                    partition BY bill, CONVERT(DATE, bill_date)) ) > 1
              AND type IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) THEN coalesce((SELECT amount
                                            FROM   #TAB
                                            WHERE  type = 3
                                                   AND bill = t.bill),0)
         ELSE 0
       END AS Amount2
FROM   #TAB t
```

Comment: Your statement working fine. Thanks for effort. However the Amount2 column simply the amount column. It may fail when different amounts there for 1,2,3. But i will give a try for your query. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer please try it. It will give you the expected results

Answer (score 0):

Try my code mentioned below -

```
SELECT b.*
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN a.amount IS NOT NULL
                THEN a.amount
            END
        )
FROM (
    SELECT b.*
    FROM (
        SELECT bill
            ,max(type) AS type
        FROM TableA
        WHERE type IN (
                1
                ,2
                ,3
                )
        GROUP BY bill
            ,cast(bill_date AS DATE)
        HAVING count(*) = 3
        ) AS a
    RIGHT JOIN TableA AS b ON a.bill = b.bill
        AND a.type = b.type
    ) AS a
RIGHT JOIN TableA AS b ON a.bill = b.bill
    AND a.type = b.type
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Not working.. however the above one which i accepted is working fine. Thank you